# How can I find out the command to run a program installed under wine?

Tags: wine, ps

I installed PDFXEditor under wine. I can start the program from desktop menu, but I like to find out which command is run, so while the program is running,

```
$ ps aux | grep -i PDFXEdit
t        23516  7.6  1.6 2129760 133368 ?      Ssl  08:11   0:02 C:\PROG~5P2\TRAC~EK1\PDF_~VHK\PDFXEdit.exe
```

The last field `C:\PROG~5P2\TRAC~EK1\PDF_~VHK\PDFXEdit.exe` in the output isn't a command. So what is it?

Isn't `ps` supposed to tell me the command in the last field? Why does it not?

How can I find out the actual command to run the program?

Thanks.

---

Update 1:

```
$ find ~/.local/share/applications/wine/ -name "*.desktop" -exec sed '/Exec=/!d' {} \;
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/t/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Amazon/Amazon\\ Kindle/Uninstall\\ Kindle.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/t/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Amazon/Amazon\\ Kindle/Kindle.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Adobe\\ Digital\\ Editions\\ 4.5.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/t/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Tracker\\ Software/Tracker\\ Updater.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/t/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Tracker\\ Software/PDF-XChange\\ Lite\\ V6/PDF-XChange\\ Lite\\ V6\\ License\\ Agreement.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/t/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Tracker\\ Software/PDF-XChange\\ Lite\\ V6/PDF-XChange\\ Lite\\ V6\\ pdfSaver.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/t/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Tracker\\ Software/PDF-XChange\\ Lite\\ V6/PDF-XChange\\ Lite\\ V6\\ User\\ Manual.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/t/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Tracker\\ Software/PDF-XChange\\ Editor/PDF-XChange\\ Editor\\ Help.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/t/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Tracker\\ Software/PDF-XChange\\ Editor/PDF-XChange\\ Editor\\ License\\ Agreement.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/t/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Tracker\\ Software/PDF-XChange\\ Editor.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Adobe/Adobe\\ Digital\\ Editions\\ 4.5/Help.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Adobe/Adobe\\ Digital\\ Editions\\ 4.5/Adobe\\ Digital\\ Editions\\ 4.5.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Adobe/Adobe\\ Digital\\ Editions\\ 4.5/Home\\ Page.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Adobe/Adobe\\ Digital\\ Editions\\ 4.5/Uninstall.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\\ Menu/Programs/PDF-XChange\\ PDF\\ Viewer/PDF-Viewer\\ Users\\ Manual.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\\ Menu/Programs/PDF-XChange\\ PDF\\ Viewer/PDF-Viewer.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\\ Menu/Programs/PDF-XChange\\ PDF\\ Viewer/Tracker\\ Updater.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\\ Menu/Programs/PDF-XChange\\ PDF\\ Viewer/PDF-Viewer\\ License.lnk
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/t/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/t/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\\ Menu/Programs/PDF-XChange\\ PDF\\ Viewer/Uninstall.lnk
```

---

Update 2

```
$ wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Tracker\ Software/PDF\ Editor/PDFXEdit.exe 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

Update 3

```
$ wine  "/home/t/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Tracker Software/PDF Editor/PDFXEdit.exe"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

Update 4

```
$ export WINEARCH=win32 
$ wine  "/home/t/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Tracker Software/PDF Editor/PDFXEdit.exe"
wine: WINEARCH set to win32 but '/home/t/.wine' is a 64-bit installation
```

Answer (score 2):

`C:\PROG~5P2\TRAC~EK1\PDF_~VHK\PDFXEdit.exe` is a scrambled and useless Windows path, but at least you got the name of your executable: `PDFXEdit.exe`

Search your `~/.wine` directory for this file with

```
find ~/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ -name "PDFXEdit.exe"
```

and once you found the correct path surround it with quotes and run it using `wine "/path/to/file.exe"`. This approach can be used for other executables like `.msi` etc. as well.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find anything related to the output of the command. See my update.

Comment: What is the command that I can run in terminal, according to the line of output?

Comment: Is it possible to find out a command of the form `wine /path/to/exe`?

Comment: In the same terminal, try `export WINEARCH=win32` and then the last `wine` command again.

Comment: Let's continue this in this chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66710/